# Sending Ctrl-Right to Vim inside Tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm using Vim that's running inside a tmux session. Within Vim, I have Ctrl-Right bound to :tabnext:

```
map <C-right> :tabnext<CR>      "next tab
```

I want to be able to invoke this binding even when Vim is inside tmux, so I added the following to my .tmux.conf:

```
bind-key -n C-Right send-keys C-Right
```

But this doesn't have any discernible effect on either Tmux or Vim! What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you have a custom bind for this? It's already bound to `gt` (and previous is `gT`).

Comment: does your mapping work in a terminal vim? I mean, **not** in tmux, just in a terminal?

Comment: @Kent Why wouldn't it? Works for me.

Comment: @glts it depends on how does your terminal interpret the `<c-right>` some (xfce/gnome...) terminal works some (urxvt..etc.) not.

Comment: @Kent Yes it works just fine from within Konsole (KDE)

Comment: @timss Because I find C-Right more convenient.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got something working though I'm very much treading unknown territory here. Perhaps someone else can fill in the rest.

The first difference I noticed when starting up Vim in the terminal and Vim inside tmux was in their `'term'` setting.

When asked `:set term?`, ordinary terminal Vim answered `xterm-256color`, but tmux Vim answered `screen`. It's important to understand that the exact key codes sent in the terminal depend on the type of the terminal.

One solution is simply to make tmux and Vim speak the same language. In tmux:

```
set-option -gw xterm-keys on
bind-key -n C-Right send-keys C-Right
```

In Vim:

```
:set term=xterm-256color
```

Now Vim and tmux understand each other's terminal key codes and your key strokes will make it all the way to Vim.

Comment: +1 for pointing out `:set term=xterm-256color`, which `tmux` sets to `screen`  for all shells running inside it.

Comment: in my case it was set to screen-256color